# Tag Synonym Request: “Irish English” → “Hiberno-English”

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, tag-synonyms, retag-request

## **tl;dr**:

1. Wikipedia uses *Hiberno-English* as the canonical form and uses *Irish English* as the autolinked-to synonym for the same thing.
2. *Irish**–**English* with a dash and *Irish**-**English* with a hyphen are two different things, a fine distinction that we cannot represent in tags due to lack of en-dash support. In contrast, *Hiberno-English* suffers no such ambiguity.
3. No matter which of [hiberno-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiberno-english) or [irish-english](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irish-english) is chosen as the canonical form, those should **not** be two different tags; one should be the synonym of the other.

---

I’ve gone through and retagged all the questions tagged with **Irish-English** to [be tagged with **Hiberno-English**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiberno-english). I’ve also spruced up its [tag wiki and excerpt](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/hiberno-english/info) a wee bit.

Could we therefore please have a tag synonym/merge/magical-alias created so that whenever someone types in “Irish English” for a tag, this gets automagically retagged to [“Hiberno-English”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English) instead?

---

**Background and Reasoning:**

The canonical name for this on Wikipedia is [**Hiberno-English**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hiberno-English), which is why I chose that version of the tag.  Now, they do recognize the synonym:  if you look up [**Irish English**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irish_English) on Wikipedia, you will notice how it automatically redirects you to the Hiberno-English link.  All I’m asking if for us to have the same sort of aliasing that they do, to help prevent confusion.

Why they should have chosen the H-version as the canonical form and the I-version as the synonym — rather than vice versa — I cannot say for sure. I only know that is what they have done, and it seems sensible enough to me.

Certainly the word *Irish* used alone when referring to language leaves it ambiguous whether it’s an English tongue or a Celtic one that’s under discussion.  Imagine if you are talking “Irish–English relations”, like “US–UK relations”: both of those are talking about two different countries, and it is asking a lot for people to tell the difference between an en dash and a hyphen in *Irish–English* compared with *Irish-English*  (Plus our tagset doesn’t support dashes, only hyphens.)  With “Hiberno-English”, no such ambiguity exists, so for that reason if no other it seems the preferable term.

I don’t actually care particularly strongly just which one of *Hiberno-English* or *Irish English* winds up being the canonical version. I just think that because the two terms do in fact here on ELU refer to the same thing, **there should not be two distinct tags** for the same thing.  That requires a tag synonym and a merge.

I did the work of the retagging because there were questions in both tags, but I don’t strongly care how it reads **provided** that the two spellings go to the same place.  This is exactly what tag synonyms are for.  But because there are only a couple of dozen questions with this tag, we don’t have the power as tagsyn voters to effect this change.  That’s why this is a support request for moderatorial intervention.

If people have an allergy to *Hiberno-English* as “too fancy” and don’t care that “Irish-English” is ambiguous in a way that the former term is not, so be it. There still should be only a pair of synonyms.  But those same people will probably also next request that the *Orthography* tag and its tag-synonym *Spelling* have their canonicity reversed.

Comment: What was wrong with 'Irish-English'?

Comment: @Mitch: Both tags existed, so I am trying to merge them. I flipped a coin.

Comment: I'm going to ask, knowing that I risk being ridiculed but I don't see the difference in *meaning*  between `Irish—English` and its hyphenated version `Irish-English`. If the tags make no distinction between a dash and a hyphen, where is the problem? I would also have thought a tag called `gaelic-celtic` would take care of any ambiguities that an `Irish` tag (if it exists) might have.

Comment: @Mari-LouA _Irish–English_ refers to something that relates to both England and Ireland and is thus comparable to _Brazilian–Mexican_ or _US–UK_ or _Chinese–Japanese_. _Irish English_ means ‘English as it is spoken in Ireland’ and is comparable to _American English_ or _British English_. Since tags have to be one word per tag and hyphens are used as word separators, the tag ends up being called [tag:irish-english], even though it’s really two words.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet fine, I get that Irish-English is ELU's tag system for writing "Irish English". Whenever I have written the full form of BrEng (Some prefer BE) it been two words without the hyphen. I'm asking about the difference in meaning between the hyphen and the dash, in Irish—English and Irish-English. A difference which tags cannot account for.

Comment: @Mari-LouA *Irish* is a language in its own right, a Celtic tongue.  The *Hiberno-* prefix, in contrast, is not.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that *Irish* is a language.  That's why I suggested a `gaelic-celtic` tag that specifically refers to the Irish and Scottish languages and avoids any misunderstanding that an `Irish` tag (which is currently non-existent)  might create.

Comment: Re typo in “I only that that”, I can correct it to “I only thot that” if you like :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As requested by tchrist:

Unlike Hugo, I would prefer *Hiberno-English* as the main tag.

Within the field of linguistics (as applied to Ireland and her languages in particular), *Hiberno-English* (or *Hibernian English*) and *Irish English* are actually two distinct terms with (slightly) different meanings:

- **Hiberno-English** is the variant of English that is currently spoken in various dialects on the Emerald Isle (Republic and Northern Ireland)
- **Irish English** is English spoken as a second language by native Irish speakers, with all the usual first-language influences that entails.

In other words, a speaker of Hiberno-English is normally a native English speaker (who may or may not even know that a great many of the words they use is of Irish origin), while a speaker of Irish English is not.

Given that ELU is about English, not Irish, Hiberno-English is of greater relevance to our needs.

This distinction is (usually) upheld when dealing with the current status of Irish and English in Ireland today in linguistic articles, etc.; but outside this narrow scope, they are nearly always synonymic, and even linguists who are not specialised in Ireland in particular often use them indiscriminately.

As such, it would be absurdly persnickety and nitpickety of us to have separate, non-synonymic tags for the two here (especially since one of them would be all but useless in our context anyway), and I thus agree entirely with Hugo that they should be synonymised; but I think we should let ourselves be guided by the consensus within the field, even if it isn’t very widely known outside a small field of scholars.

Comment: Excellent, except we don't say *Emerald Isle*. To refer to the geographical unit, just say *the island of Ireland*.

Comment: @smci [I can see that you are not a poet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emerald_Isle).

Comment: Do you have a citation for the statement that "Irish English" refers to the English of Irish speakers? I've never come across that. Rather I hear both "Irish English" and "Hiberno-English" used in Ireland of the form of English we speak, with some not using the latter for those form that are more influenced by Ulster Scots than by Irish.

Comment: @Jon I’m afraid I don’t have one at the ready. I _think_ Ó Siadhail in his book on Modern Irish uses _Irish English_ in this way, but it’s been a long while since I read it, and I can’t be quite sure. I’m also fairly sure that in some of Pedersen’s surveys on the Irish of Ros Goill or Tory or some such place, he talks about how Irish English has influenced the local Hiberno-English in modern, recorded times. Apart from that, I come across articles every so often where it’s clear they use the terms this way, but I usually just read and discard them out of incidental interest …

Comment: Thy wish is granted.

Comment: It's usual to use Scottish English for English spoken in Scotland (as distinct to Scots or Scottish Gaelic), American English for English spoken in the USA, Indian English for English in the Indian subcontinent, Jamaican English for English spoken in Jamaica (as distinct to Patois/Patwah), etc. I don't see why we need to break from that model for the Irish.

Answer (score 10):

I agree to make the two synonyms.

I'd prefer Irish-English to be the main tag and Hiberno-English to redirect to it, as it's perhaps a bit clearer, but don't mind too much either way.